# Wrong interpretation of probability in a scientific paper

Tags: probability, cellular-automata

I've been reading a scientific paper about a cellular automaton which models the spread of cancer cells. I've almost finished my model in C++ when I noticed a possible error in probability interpretation on the authors' part. It's really strange because the paper was used as a source in a different paper which seemingly made the same mistake. I am writing here to make sure whether I am wrong or the authors of both papers are.

I will try to explain the possible mistake:

When we choose a cancer cell, it can:

- Infect other cells with a probability of $r_{\text{infect}}$.
- Be caught by a immune cell with a probability of $r_{\text{caught}}$.
- It can do nothing with a possibility of $1-(r_{\text{infect}}+r_{\text{caught}})$

The authors say that a random floating point number $r$ between $0$ and $1$ must be generated. Then they propose an algorithm:

If the generated number $r$ is smaller than $r_{\text{infect}}$, then the cell will infect. Else if the generated number $r$ is *smaller* than $1-r_{\text{caught}}$, the cell will get caught. If it is bigger than that, the cell will do nothing.

This, however, seems wrong to me. If $r_{\text{infect}}$ is $0.7$ and $r_{\text{caught}}$ is $0.2$, then the algorithm would actually make the possibility of getting caught $0.1$, not $0.2$, because $1-0.2$ is $0.8$ and therefore, in order to be caught, the necessary floating point number
will have to lie between $0.7$ and $0.8$, which makes its probability $0.1$, not $0.2$.

It seems like a weird mistake because the authors then talk about the rules of a different kind of cell, where the probabilities are correct. So I don't know whether the model is valid or not.

Here's the first and original paper with the proposed rules (on the far bottom of the paper):
[First paper](https://www.jkps.or.kr/journal/download_pdf.php?spage=1652&volume=49&number=4)

And here's the second paper which uses the rules from the first: [Second paper](https://sci-hub.se/https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352914817302435)

Comment: Looking at page 1664 of the first paper, the $r \le 1-r_{\text{binding}}?$  box looks strange in the way you describe, while the $r \ge  1-r_{\text{lysis}}?$ box looks what you might expect to work.

Comment: @Henry yes, that's what I noticed too; as I wrote in my post *"... then they talk about the rules of a different kind of cell, where the probabilities are correct"*. It does not make sense to my why the probabilities would be left like that in the complex cell and not in the proliferating cell.

Comment: It's weird that they would even include such an implementation detail in the paper. They should just say that they sample from the discrete distribution with the desired probabilities, and leave the implementation in the code.

Comment: I would assume it's probably just a typo in the paper. If they had that bug in their actual code, it would be obvious that varying $r_{\rm caught}$ has the opposite effect to what's expected.